# Android manifest keeps putting an error line back

Tags: android, manifest, android-appcompat

I'm building an Android app using Android Studio 1.0.2. I wanted to create a loading screen and made an activity for that. The activity should be full screen so I insert the  android theme line for no actionbar. using AppCompat.

Now something is going wrong, I guess the theme can't be found so the app won't build. But when I remove the line to build without it, it will just add the line back and give me error: Error:(20, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen').

I have tried with a bunch of themes and it keep getting stuck. After some clean or rebuild it will build again but give me errors because I should be using AppCompat.

Over the manifest there is also a line saying: Files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited.

Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="nl.toteki_apps.beertaster"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="nl.toteki_apps.beertaster.activity.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="nl.toteki_apps.beertaster.activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **@style/Theme.AppCompat.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen** (without "android:")
because compat themes/styles are not not from android package/namespace

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you were trying to edit generated file. Please check if you are changing the main `AndroidManifest.xml`file which is located under `yourProjectName/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`